# MultipleChooserPanel: this.chooserWidgetFactory.openModal is not a function

Tags: wagtail, wagtail-admin

I upgraded from wagtail 4 to wagtail 5.0.2. When I try to open a MultipleChooserPanel I get the following js error in the browser console:

```js
Uncaught TypeError: this.chooserWidgetFactory.openModal is not a function
    MultipleChooserPanel http://10.10.10.57:10000/api/static/wagtailadmin/js/page-editor.js?v=ce9bf046:1
page-editor.js:1:4815
    MultipleChooserPanel http://10.10.10.57:10000/api/static/wagtailadmin/js/page-editor.js?v=ce9bf046:1
```

This works however on a fresh install of wagtail. To recreate the project from scratch is not an option because the current project is huge. Any idea where the error could originate from?

I already tried clearing the browser cache, use a different browser and I ran this command: `./manage.py collectstatic --noinput --clear`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly I have to provide y'all with an unsatisfying answer. The issue resolved without **any** code changes. Maybe opening another modal helps (in my case the ImageChooser)

Answer (score 0):

The problem you experienced might be related to this issue: https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues/10646.

In my case it was the 'Locale' model I referenced in the FK that hadn't a proper chooser viewset.

```
# models.py

class SiteSupportedLocale(Orderable):

    settings = ParentalKey(
        to='home.SiteActiveLocalesSettings',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='active_locales',
    )

    locale = models.ForeignKey(
        to='wagtailcore.Locale',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='supported_locales',
    )

    class Meta(Orderable.Meta):
        verbose_name = _('Site supported locale')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Site supported locales')


@register_setting
class SiteActiveLocalesSettings(ClusterableModel, BaseSiteSetting):

    panels = [
        MultipleChooserPanel('active_locales', label=_('Active locale'), chooser_field_name="locale")
    ]

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('Site active locale')
        verbose_name_plural = _('Site active locales')

# views.py

class LocaleChooserViewSet(ChooserViewSet):

    model = 'wagtailcore.Locale'
    choose_one_text = _('Choose a locale')
    choose_another_text = _('Choose another locale')


locale_chooser_viewset = LocaleChooserViewSet('locale_chooser')

# wagtail_hooks.py

@hooks.register('register_admin_viewset')
def register_viewset():
    return locale_chooser_viewset
```

Comment: yeah its related to that because I opened that issue but I'll try your solution as soon as the issue comes up again

Comment: @N.Ahlers you're welcome! I was pointed to that issue by one of the wagtail collaborators.